# LAMP stack on Raspberry Pi 3 not loading CSS

Tags: css, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, apache2

I recently purchased a Raspberry Pi 3 and installed Ubuntu Mate, with the intention of setting up a web server.  I installed...
Apache/2.4.18
MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21 
PHP 7.0.28

Here is my header...

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/clc-338x64.jpg" type="image/x-icon">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/web/assets/mobirise-icons/mobirise-icons.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/tether/tether.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/socicon/css/styles.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/dropdown/css/style.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/theme/css/style.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/mobirise/css/mbr-additional.css" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script" rel="stylesheet">
</head>`
```

When I navigate to the html file directly

file:///var/www/html/index.html

I see the website just fine. --> [Fully Functional Site Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaKSW.jpg)

but when I attempt to view the site with the Pi's IP address

10.0.0.185

I get this instead --> [Missing CSS Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK37w.png)

what is it that is preventing all the css from loading?

Comment: Apache error log and config will be extremely useful to address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing it by accident... I messed with my permissions of the website directory and changed it from "root" and then freaked out because root was no longer an option to get it back... then I used the following command.

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

and now my website shows up as intended when I use the ip address!